# Network images keeps disappearing when scrolling list view in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a list view where the image from api is loaded, I noticed that the image keeps disappearing for few seconds when scrolling once in a while. Here is the code on the image part only:

```
Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0,left:15.0,right:1.0,bottom:0.0),
constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(
   height: 130.0,
   width: 150.0,
),
decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(artworksAndEventsFinal[index]['thumbnail']),fit: BoxFit.cover,),
            ),
           child: new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                   new Positioned(
                   right: 0.0,
                   bottom: 0.0,
                   child: Container(
                   height: 24.0,
                   padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:5.0,left:10.0,right:5.0,bottom:5.0),
             decoration: new BoxDecoration(
             color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
             ),
             child: new Text(artworksAndEventsFinal[index]['year'],
                    style: new TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 11.0,
                    color: Colors.white
                     )
                    ),
             )
            ),
            new Positioned(
                right: 3.0,
                top: 0.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.favorite_border,color: 
                Colors.white,),
                ),
            ],
          )
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: show the code how you build list because I tried with ListView.builder and it's working fine

Comment: I have the same problem when dealing with File Images. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List View creates the widget when it is visible. Thus only the visible child has the image and the one disappearing removes the widget and the one not loaded yet doesn't fetch the image.
This approach has wonderful benefit of optimal memory utilization. Say you have 1000 of cards with images in List view and showing just 2-3 on the screen at the moment, thus only for the 2-3 visble card image will be loaded and when user will scroll and bring the other cards from the list, it will load images only when visible.

If you want to cache the images, please consider using package [Cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

Comment: Not OP, but I'm using cached_network_image and still having the issue where the cached images load quite slow when I scroll back to top, resulting in empty view for a second. I guess it's because of large-sized images.

Comment: thank you @Ashish Sukhija I will give that a try, Zerocchi I read online it only happens on the debug apps but not after you build it for production? have you tired to test on a production built version?

Comment: @Mikethetechy I tried in `--profile` and `--release` mode, unfortunately it's still happened.

Comment: Did anyone get the solution?

Answer (score 20):

Change the `cacheExtent` value to 9999 and it works for me:

```
ListView.builder(
  cacheExtent: 9999,
  …
),
```

Comment: Add some explanation on why to use it and what's to expect if use cacheExtent. Using huge numbers it's likely disabling the main feature of ListView.builder, that is building and displaying item only when visible, saving memory.
Use wisely.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin`, the answer from other post have helped me, you can go to this link :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65625128

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a `ValueKey` to each item of the list.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Items are still disappearing

Answer (score 0):

Set large number to `cacheExtent` value like 99999 and it will work.

Kindly view what `cachExtent` do from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348382/what-exactly-does-cacheextent-property-in-listview-builder-do#answer-57361352)