# Flutter : Prevent FutureBuilder always refresh every change screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have FutureBuilder to fetch User profil from API and code to fetch user like this :

```
 Future<List<UserModel>> getUserByUsername({@required String username}) async {
    try {
      final response =
          await _client.get("$_baseUrl/getUserByUsername?username=$username");
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
        List userList = responseJson['data'];
        final result = userList
            .map<UserModel>((json) => UserModel.fromJson(json))
            .toList();
        return result;
      } else {
        throw CustomError(responseJson['message']);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

[image: future builder]

If you can see in above GIF, My FutureBuilder are inside BottomNavigationBar. Every i change the screen/page from BottomNavigationBar and come back to my FutureBuilder is always refresh !

How can i fixed it to only once to refresh ?

## Home Screen

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final username = Provider.of<SharedPreferencesFunction>(context).username;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          CardTime(),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: userApi.getUserByUsername(username: username),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<List<UserModel>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      snapshot.error.toString(),
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  final user = snapshot.data[0];
                  return CardProfil(
                    imageUrl: "${userApi.baseImageUrl}/${user.fotoUser}",
                    detailProfil: [
                      Text(
                        user.namaUser,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(user.idDevice),
                    ],
                  );
                }
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Shared Preferences Function

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class SharedPreferencesFunction extends ChangeNotifier {
  SharedPreferencesFunction() {
    initialSharedPreferences();
    getUsername();
  }
  String _username;
  String get username => _username;

  void initialSharedPreferences() {
    getUsername();
  }

  Future updateUsername(String username) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await pref.setString("username", username);
    //! It's Important !!! After update / remove sharedpreferences  , must called getUsername() to updated the value.
    getUsername();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future removeUsername() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result = await pref.remove("username");
    //! It's Important !!! After update / remove sharedpreferences  , must called getUsername() to updated the value.
    getUsername();
    print(result);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future getUsername() async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result = pref.getString("username");
    _username = result;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

final sharedpref = SharedPreferencesFunction();
```

> Update Question

I already try Initialize FutureBuilder and use **initState** and **didChangeDependencies** . But new problem is , if i initialize inside **initState** my profil not rebuild because **Provider listen=false**.
If i using **didChangeDependencies** my FutureBuilder still refresh every i change screen.
Something wrong ?

## Using initState

[image]

## Using didChangeDependencies

[image]

Comment: Could you have a look at following links: https://medium.com/@lucassaltoncardinali/keeping-state-with-the-bottom-navigation-bar-in-flutter-69e4168878e1

https://codewithandrea.com/articles/2018-07-07-multiple-navigators-bottom-navigation-bar/

Answer (score 7):

Initialize the `Future` during `initState` or `didChangeDependencies` instead.

```dart
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Future<List<UserModel>> user;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();

    // must use listen false here
    final username = Provider.of<SharedPreferencesFunction>(context, listen: false).username;
    user = userApi.getUserByUsername(username: username);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    final username = Provider.of<SharedPreferencesFunction>(context).username;
    user = userApi.getUserByUsername(username: username);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: user,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              // ...
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not work, i already using **initState** and **didChangeDepedencies**. If i using initState my profil is not found because the **Provider** listen =false https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf3p2.gif. If i using **didChangeDependencies** my FutureBuilder still refresh every i change the screen https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf3p2.gif . Something wrong with my code ?

Comment: You have the same gif on both links.

Comment: But a few things you can check. With the `didChangeDependencies`, are you calling `notifyListeners` in `SharedPreferencesFunction` for every tab change or a `setState` higher up in the widget tree? You could try and isolate just the `HomeScreen` and see if it still refreshes on `setState` or etc.

Comment: I added my **shared Preferences Function**

Comment: You need to await `getUsername`, and why not directly set `_username`. You are calling `notifyListeners` twice for `setUsername` and `removeUsername`.

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar case and use `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` on each view / page / tab bar view / widget / child to keep the page not refreshing every time I go back and forth through the tab bar.

```
class YourClass extends StatefulWidget {
  YourClass({
    Key key
  }): super(key key);

  @override
  _YourClassState createState() => _YourClassState();
}

// Must include AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
class _YourClassState extends State<YourClass> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  Future resultGetData;

  void getData() {
    setState(() {
      resultGetData = getDataFromAPI();
    });
  }

  // Must include
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // Must include
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: resultGetAllByUserIdMCId,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // ...
        // Some Code
        // ...
      }
    );
  }

}
```

If you want to refresh the data you could use `RefreshIndicator` that runs the `getData()` function. Put this code inside `FutureBuilder`. The `key: PageStorageKey(widget.key)` will keep the scroll in the exact same place where you left of.

```
return RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () async {
    getData();
  },
  child: ListView.separated(
    key: PageStorageKey(widget.key),
    itemCount: data.length,
    separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Divider(height: 0);
    },
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ...;
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [IndexedStack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack/IndexedStack.html) as the parent of tabbar.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your Future Builder in a Stateful Widget then define a
late final Future myFuture;
then you have to initialize it in the initstate so the future will be executed only one time.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).