# What is the cacheExtent field of ListView.builder in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57052924/16124033) and used the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750222/16124033).

Answer:

> Change the `cacheExtent` value to 9999 and it works for me:
>
> ```
> ListView.builder(
>   cacheExtent: 9999,
>   …
> ),
> ```

However, I have a question, what is the `cacheExtent` field and why should I use it?

My code:

```
ListView.builder(
  cacheExtent: 9999,
  …
),
```

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more information.

What is the `cacheExtent` field of `ListView.builder`? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cacheExtent` is the size of the area drawn before the visible part of the screen, it has two parts: one part for items already displayed before the visible area, and one part for after the visible area.

When you make the size of the `cacheExtent` very large, you can almost make the `ListView.builder` draw all of its children before and after the currently displayed item, which is why the delayed behavior disappears. But you have to use the cache wisely, because too large a cache can cause unpleasant side effects, such as a significant increase in the user's internet traffic. Lazy loading is there for a reason.